# How to convert Comma separated string to KeyValuePair of LIST or IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, split

I have a dynamic string:

It looks like `"1: Name, 2: Another Name"`  this. I want to split it and convert it to a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` or `IEnmerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`

I tried this.

```
myString.Split(',').Select(s => s => new KeyValuePair<int, string>( Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(':'), s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(':')) + 1))))
```

Does not to help much. I can do strings of Dictionary or a foreach or a for loop. I rather do it as a key value pair lambda expression one liner.

Comment: for the select's substrings, should you split on ":" instead?  In fact, would seem to be Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(':')[0]) and s.Split(':')[1]

Comment: Sorry it is reversed but still it does not work. I will edit the question.

Comment: at the time I saw it, you had commas on all. Inside the select I would split on colon and handle parsing and that should get you there.

Comment: I was missing the second split inside select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myString.Split(',').Select(s => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(
   int.Parse(s.Split(':').GetValue(0).ToString()),
   s.Split(':').GetValue(1).ToString()
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split twice first by comma, then by colon. Try this code:

```
var input = "1: Name, 2: Another Name";

var list = input.Split(',')
    .Select(p =>
    {
        var kv = p.Split(':');
        return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(int.Parse(kv[0].Trim()), kv[1]);
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

WARNING: No exception handling

```
myString.Split(',').Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(int.Parse(x.Split(':')[0]), x.Split(':')[1]))
```

Comment: This is also the answer but Abdullah answered first.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve that with the beauty of regex:

```
var result = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches("1: Name, 2: Another Name", @"((\d+): ([\w ]+))"))
{
    result.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value), match.Groups[3].Value));
}
```